# SSIS Package: convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types

Tags: sql-server, oracle, unicode, ssis

I am connecting to an Oracle DB and the connection works, but I get the following error for some of the columns:

```
Description: Column "RESOURCE_NAME" cannot convert between unicode 
and non-unicode string data types.
```

Value for RESOURCE_NAME:

- For Oracle: `VARCHAR2(200 BYTE)`
- For SQL Server: `VARCHAR(200 BYTE)`

I can connect to the Oracle DB via Oracle SQL Developer without any issues.  Also, I have the SSIS package setting `Run64BitRuntime = False`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Oracle data type `VARCHAR2` appears to be equivalent to `NVARCHAR` in SQL Server, or `DT_WSTR` in SSIS. [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036.aspx)

You will have to convert using the ***Data Conversion Transformation***, or `CAST` or `CONVERT` functions in SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

If the package works in one machine and doesn't in other; Try setting the NLS_LANG to right language, territory and character set and test the package.

```
[Command Prompt]> set NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way around this to to open the SSIS package *in notepad* (the dtsx file) and do a global find and replace of all instances of **validateExternalMetadata="True"** with **validateExternalMetadata="False"**.

note: we encountered this issue when connecting to an Oracle 11g database on Linux through SSIS.

Comment: I believe `.dtsx` is correct.  Make a back-up of the file before you touch it.

Answer (score 1):

on oledb source ->advanced editor options->input/output columns->output columns->select RESOURCE_NAME column and change Data type as DT_WSTR and length also u can change as required

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL command in SSIS and use `CONVERT` or `CAST`. If SSIS still gives you an error its because of the metadata. Here is how you can fix it.

1. Open the Advanced Editor.
2. Under the Input and Output properties, Expand Source Output.
3. Expand Output columns
4. Select the column which is causing the issue.
5. Go to Data Type Properties and change the DataType to your desired type DT_STR, DT_Text etc.

Comment: This saved me! Thanks

Comment: Where can I find the advanced editor for an SSIS package?

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg - In the Data Flow task, drag the ODBC source from Other Sources and right click the source. You'll find Advanced Editor.

Comment: This - the solution I'm used to - doesn't work for me.  I set the column to DT_WSTR (correct length).  OK.  Go back into Adv. Editor: it's flipped back to DT_STR.   This is even before execution or validation.  ValidateExternalMetadata on or off makes no difference.  It's the MS Oracle driver being a pain, I think...

Answer (score 1):

You can just double-click on the "Data Conversion" block in the Data Flow and for every item change it to: "Unicode String [DT_WSTR]"

Works

Answer (score 0):

If everything failed from above. Create a table variable and insert the data into it. Then select all records as source. use SET NOCOUNT ON in the script.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a very similar problem even using SQL Server rather than Oracle. In my case, I was using a Flat File as a data source, so I just went in to the Flat File Connection Manager and manually changed the column type to be a Unicode string:
[image]

I don't know if this would fix your problem or not, but it helped me - hopefully someone else will be helped too. (I was inspired to try that by [this previous answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53787046/4032703) BTW, just to give credit where credit's due).