# SSIS Package Error - cannot convert unicode to non unicode

Tags: .net, sql-server, unicode, ssis, oracle11g

I am new in SSIS Package development. Since few days I am facing an unexpected issue with SSIS package.

My SSIS Package is developed with using two different database. In Source, I have used SQL Server and Oracle and in destination I've used Oracle. SSIS Package was working as expected since few years but one of my client upgraded his server from 32bit to 64bit operating system.

Issue is with using Oracle database. Earlier, I was using MSDORA.1 for connectivity of Oracle database but one of Microsoft forum, I read that they've not launched MSDORA.1 yet. So I have to convert my SSIS package with OraOELDB.Oracle.1 drivers. Everything is working as expected in one of the server but when I deployed on client's server it is giving me below error.

```
<<MY_COLUMN>> cannot convert unicode to non-unicode string data types
```

I had VARCHAR2 data type in all columns of Oracle database table.

Comment: just because something is a varchar doesn't mean it's a UNICODE varchar.

Comment: @MarcB: Thanks. I understand that we have to add some data type conversation in SSIS Package but as I told you I am facing this issue with Client's server only. So wanted to understand what is exactly happening.

Comment: you say the client upgraded their server. so it's not the same environment as before. make SURE the schema in their server exactly matches the schema on your test/devel server.

Comment: @MarcB: I've verified almost all the configuration between both servers (Mine and Client). I dint found any variation on those servers which can cause any issue regarding this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have experienced the same when changing drivers.  The OLEDB drivers for Oracle will give you "DT_WSTR" types in your SSIS.  Some other drivers (e.g Attunity) will give you "DT_STR" types for the same fields.

You need to add a step to your SSIS Package that converts those fields to the "DT_STR" data type.  You need to convert or cast.  This thread contains more information for you:  [SSIS Package: convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662210/ssis-package-cannot-convert-between-unicode-and-non-unicode-string-data-types)

Comment: IMO The fact that it "works" on one server and not another could indicate different driver versions are behaving differently.

Comment: Also I did need to set validateExternalMetadata="False" to address the next error you may encounter with the OLEDB providers for Oracle.

Comment: Yes mikey...I did the same. Instead of adding new step in SSIS Package, I changed the validateExternalMetadata= "False". It works in my server. I don't know about client's system..Does it work with with property only??? Also, I read same post what you provided buddy before posting question here..

Comment: Try adding the new step also.  Explicitly convert from DT_WSTR to DT_STR.

Comment: Thanx Mikey..Let me try with property first then if works then let it be or else i have to add new step for conversation of column...I am telling you you this because you know I don't wanna make more iteration with my client.

Comment: I hope sounds should also pretty gud for me after applying this change...Will definitely let u knw the status..

Comment: When a package receives the signal to start, the SSIS engine looks at every component and verifies that it exists, the meta data signatures match, etc. Then, when the component gets the signal that it can run, the metadata is then rechecked prior to execution. The `validateExternalMetadata` property merely indicates that the SSIS engine should not verify the integrity of a component during the initial package validation phase. Editing a package also fires off the first validation phase which is why I presume it is prescribed in this situation.

Comment: @mikey Hey dude...sorry for late but resolved this issue by setting only property which is "validateExternalMetadata".. Thanks a lot buddy.. :)